# Django looks for templates in my .envs folder (+ Django Admin)

Tags: django, django-templates, virtualenv, django-settings, django-errors

I have my folders set up like this:

```
~/projects/myproject/
~/.envs/myproject/
```

My app folders look like this:

```
myapp/
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── forms.py
├── migrations/
├── models.py
├── tests/
├── templates/
├── urls.py
├── views.py
```

I just implemented a custom password reset view, because I wanted to use my own templates. The problem is, that the password reset view does not find my template. Here is my view:

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:password_reset_complete")
    template_name = "accounts/registration/password_reset_confirm.html"
```

And here is the error message that I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /auth/reset/MQ/set-password/
accounts/registration/password_reset_confirm.html.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/auth/reset/MQ/set-password/
Django Version: 1.11.13
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
accounts/registration/password_reset_confirm.html.
Exception Location: /Users/jan/.envs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 53
Python Executable:  /Users/jan/.envs/myproject/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/jan/Dev/Misc Tutorial/myproject',
 '/Users/jan/.envs/myproject/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/jan/.envs/myproject/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/jan/.envs/myproject/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/jan/.envs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

How can I get Django to find my custom templates? From the error I can tell that he looks in my virtual environments.

I tried specifying the templates path like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The code for this I got from the Django documentation. Unfortunately this doesn't help. If you have any idea how I can fix this, I would be very thankful!

(On a related note, I also tried to use django-admin instead of manage.py, because the official docs recommend it. But I couldn't set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env variable so that it works. Maybe this problem is related.)

EDIT: The app for the account related stuff is called accounts. In it is a folder called templates, holding various other folders, one is called 'registration'.

Comment: You have an extra `.` at the end of your template name. But your question is not clear; where is the template you are trying to use? The only app you show is called "myapp"; do you have a separate accounts app? Does it have a "templates/registration" directory?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your help. Yes I removed the point, it still throws the same error.
And yes I have a seperate accounts app. Added in in the question for context. You are also correct that within the accounts app is a templates/registration directory. I just called the example app myapp.

Comment: From the docs: "manage.py does the same thing as django-admin but takes care of a few things for you: 1) It puts your project’s package on sys.path. 2) It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file." By going to manage.py you might find configuring your Django project easier.

Comment: Thank you @pydanny. I'm going to use manage.py then! And do you know what could cause Django to only look for templates inside the .envs folder?

Comment: Without seeing the entire source code, I can't begin to diagnose why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kinda solved.

Circumvented the django-admin problem by using manage.py just as [pydanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93270/pydanny) suggested.

And I just had my templates configured wrongly.
Here is the new view I used:

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:password_reset_complete")
    template_name = "registration/password_reset_confirm.html"
```

I also put the template folder in my project root like this:

```
myproject
  accounts/
  ...
  myproject/
  templates/
```

The `registration/` folder is now within this `templates/` directory.

Together with the following settings everything works now, thank you for everyone that helped!

Settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: The solution here is the last step. The string you pass to the join would be your folder/path (of where your templates are stored) at the root level. In my case I am using a templates folder within every single app, so my solution was to add a dir for every single app as 'foobar/templates'. Pretty sure there should be another way of doing it but I'm new to django.

Comment: To update my previous comment. You can just add your app to the INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py, much simpler than what I said earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Django was looking for templates in my venv dir (my virtual environment dir) too, in my case, I solved it after I added my app in the settings file of the main project dir.

Basically in your app dir, there's an `apps.py` file which has a class named
`*YOURAPPNAME*Config`. In my case, the app is accounts so the class is `AccountsConfig`. Then go into your main project dir, which is located in same directory as your `manage.py` file, open `settings.py`, scroll down to `INSTALLED_APPS` and add your class there. For me it would be `accounts.apps.AccountsConfig`

Comment: This *might* a good answer, but it would be helpful if you explained your answer in more detail. *WHICH* settings file, in *WHAT* location, and *HOW* did you add it?

Comment: You don't need to highlight your edit with "Edit:". There is an edit history link beneath your answer which will show what has been added. Hi and welcome to SE.SO btw... :-)